# Requesting an Explanation of Cauchy's Integral Formula, General Form, To Express Derivatives of a Function,

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I have understood up to the Cauchy Integral Formula, including it's derivation. I would like to understand the jump from the formula to the general expression, which utilizes the formula for derivatives. Book: *Fundamentals of Complex Analysis with Applications to Engineering and Science* by E.B. Saff and A.D. Snider.

Thusfar, $\zeta$ has represented the poles of a function. $\Gamma$ represents contours, $z$ inside of $\Gamma$.

The text gives Cauchy's Integral Formula:

$$f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} dz$$

The text then says: "If in Cauchy's formula we replace $z$ by $\zeta$ and $z_0$ by $z$, then we obtain

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z} d\zeta$$

The advantage of this representation is that it suggests a formula for the derivative $f'(z)$,obtained by formally differentiating with respect to z under the integral sign. thus we are led to suspect that

$$f'(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^2} d\zeta$$

In verifying this equation we shall actually establish a more general theorem..."

What I would like to understand is *why* these replacements happen, how this thought process came about, and how this necessarily differs from the original representation.

Comment: It's just changing letters to make de-emphasize the fixed point $z_0$.

Comment: @user I figured as much, but wouldn't replacing $z_0$ with $\zeta$ make more sense, since $\zeta$ is a pole of a function (a point where the function isn't analytic), and leaving $z$ alone as it is actually $z(t)$ and parametrizes the contour? Essentially, in this case $\zeta$ has nothing to do with the zeros of a function? Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first equation,
$$f(z_0)=\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\,dz$$
we see that the value of the given integral is equal the value of the function $f$ at $z_0$.  So, the value of $f$ at a single point $z_0$ is represented by the integral.  Note here that $z_0$ is a constant.

Now, since $z$ represents complex values in the interior of $\Gamma$ we can view the Cauchy integral as representing the values for all points in the interior of $\Gamma$.  Of course to do this, we must change the variable of integration.  Hence
$$f(z)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\,d\zeta.$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. This makes sense to me, however I am still cloudy on the use of $\zeta$, as it has always been used in this text to represent the zero of denominators.

Comment: That's a matter of context. If it helps, change $\zeta$ to $w$.  In fact, some texts write the Cauchy Integral Formula in this way.